# how to loop over distinct column result out of the list returned by sparklyr's dplyr implementation?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, for-in-loop

Given the sparklyr example provided by spark studio [here](https://spark.rstudio.com/)

```
library(sparklyr)
packageVersion("sparklyr")
#‘0.8.4’
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
#* Using Spark: 2.3.0
install.packages(c("nycflights13", "Lahman"))
library(dplyr)
flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, nycflights13::flights, "flights")
src_tbls(sc)
#[1] "flights"
```

trying to loop over distinct values ,

```
carriers <- flights_tbl %>% filter(dep_delay >= 1000) %>% dplyr::select(carrier) %>% dplyr::distinct()
> carriers
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
# Database: spark_connection
  carrier
  <chr>  
1 MQ     
2 HA     
3 AA     
> typeof(carriers)
[1] "list"
```

like this:

```
 for (carrier in carriers){
      print(carrier)
    }
```

returns this unexpected result:

```
> for (carrier in carriers){
+   print(carrier)
+ }
spark connection master=local[4] app=sparklyr local=TRUE

From: flights
<Table: flights>
-> filter()
   - ~dep_delay >= 1000
-> select()
   - ~carrier
-> distinct()
```

instead of simply:

```
 MQ     
 HA     
 AA
```

how to loop over distinct values ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, apparently one shoud "collect" spark result first (see [here](https://spark.rstudio.com/dplyr/#collecting-to-r))

```
rcarriers <- collect(carriers)
> typeof(rcarriers)
[1] "list"
> for (carrier in rcarriers){
+   print(carrier)
+ }
[1] "MQ" "HA" "AA"
```